# How to write function in controller which returns some value or object?

Tags: angularjs

How to How to write function in controller which returns some value or object ?
like

```
      $scope.getTwoNumber=function(){
      var num1=9;
       var num2=10;

       var obj={first:num1,sec:num2}
       return obj;
    }


      $scope.someOtherFunc=function(){

         var numbers={};
          numbers=$scope.getTwoNumber()

      }
```

how to achieve it?

Comment: What is wrong with the example you provided?

Comment: giving me blank object back

Comment: Its working for me... create a fiddle ..

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function in controller. Example:

```
myApp.controller('thisController', function($scope){

  $scope.thisValue = false;
  function myFunction(){
    console.log('from this function');
    return true;
  }
  $scope.thisValue = myFunction();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't forget the ";" sign at the end of the function call. The rest seems fine to me. Note you have to declare the object $scope and make sure it's not empty.

For detailed information about Controllers, please read: http://php-html.net/tutorials/model-view-controller-in-php/

```
$scope.someOtherFunc(){    
  var numbers={};
  numbers=$scope.getTwoNumber();
}
```